# LoadableDetachableModel multi-threading issue

Tags: java, multithreading, wicket

We had an issue where a lot of users were hitting a page that had a lot of ajax calls on it. It took us a long time to run down and we finally found a threading issue in LoadableDetachableModel.

I think the problem is related to the fact that we have a UserModel in the Session. This UserModel extends LoadableDetachableModel. If the load() method takes too long to return then a second Thread could get a null User returned based on the fact that the attached flag is set to true before load() is called and before transientModelObject is set. To fix it we simply made our own modified version of LoadableDetachableModel that added synchronization where necessary. Since then we have had no more problems.

I looked around in the Wicket Jira site and even looked at some commits within fisheye to see if this issue had been fixed because I noticed Wicket 7 does not have an attached flag. Instead it has an enum called InternalState to fix WICKET-5916. It appears the threading issue is still present in the 7.2 version of wicket. Here is the code:

```
    @Override
public final T getObject()
{
    if (state == null || state == InternalState.DETACHED)
    {
        // prevent infinite attachment loops
        state = InternalState.ATTACHING;//<--One thread sets this, next thread gets a null object returned since load() has not completed

        transientModelObject = load();

        if (log.isDebugEnabled())
        {
            log.debug("loaded transient object " + transientModelObject + " for " + this +
                ", requestCycle " + RequestCycle.get());
        }

        state = InternalState.ATTACHED;
        onAttach();
    }
    return transientModelObject;
}
```

As you can see, if a single thread calls getObject() and gets to the line calling load() then the model has the state variable set to ATTACHING. Now, the next thread calls getObject() before the load() completes and gets a null object returned since state is not null and state is not DETACHED.

Again, I think this could only happen if you are using a LoadableDetachableModel in your Session or Application class where multiple threads could reuse the same model.

Am I missing something or should I file a bug report? Should I not be using a LoadableDetachableModel in the Session?

Comment: What do you try to achieve with putting an LDM into the session? When would it detach?

Comment: Session has a detach method. We detach it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IModel is an interface to be used by Components, and all components are single-threaded. 
Don't use a model in your session or application.

Comment: So the recommended way for keeping a user in the Session is not via some IModel that gets detached when the Session detaches? I suppose that's fine but I've been doing it that way for 10 years now. The idea of a LoadableDetachableModel works perfectly for loading a user once per request, however after thinking through the experience we had and your response I'm thinking it would be better to use  the flyweight pattern and create a lightweight serializable version of the user and store it when the user logs in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer by the way. If you have time please let me know if you have any best practices for storing the user in the session. One of our products users wicket-auth-roles and the other doesn't. The one that doesn't use auth-roles is the one that had the problem.

Comment: Just to be clear: you can use a LDM in your page, which fetches a user's identifier from the session and loads the full fledge entity from the database. Note that you don't get any threading problems with such a setup.